# sheet.getLastRowNum() gives different values

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have two excel files with a single row. I am trying to get last row number of the file. first file gives the value as 0 and the second one as 1. Any idea why there is inconsistency in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the documentation (from [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum())):

*Gets the number last row on the sheet. Owing to idiosyncrasies in the excel file format, if the result of calling this method is zero, you can't tell if that means there are zero rows on the sheet, or one at position zero. For that case, additionally call getPhysicalNumberOfRows() to tell if there is a row at position zero or not.*